# React: How to render a component twice in an HTML page?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, frontend

I have a component built using React:

**myComponent.js**

```js
    ReactDOM.render(
      <MyComponent />,
      document.getElementById('my-id')
    );
```

In my HTML, I want to render it twice. My HTML is as following:

```html
    <div id='my-id'></div>
    some html
    <div id='my-id'></div>
```

I want my React component to render twice in this page, but it only renders once for the second `div`. Is there anyway to render it twice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't have the same `id` for two or more elements in HTML. Use different `id`s

```html
    <div id='my-id-one'></div>
    some html
    <div id='my-id-two'></div>
```

and call the `ReactDOM.render` separately for each id.

```js
    ReactDOM.render(
      <MyComponent />,
      document.getElementById('my-id-one')
    );
    
    ReactDOM.render(
      <MyComponent />,
      document.getElementById('my-id-two')
    );
```

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you want to render it in 2 different places, with non-React code in between. To do that, you'll want to give your `div`s different IDs:

```
<div id='my-id></div>
some html
<div id='my-other-id></div>
```

Then render the component to each `div`:

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <MyComponent />,
    document.getElementById('my-id')
);

ReactDOM.render(
    <MyComponent />,
    document.getElementById('my-other-id')
);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do

```
ReactDOM.render(
     <div>
       <MyComponent />
       <MyComponent />
     </div>, document.getElementById('my-id') );
```

Or You could also have two `div` tags with different id

```
<div id='one'></div>
some html
<div id='two'></div>
```

then

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <MyComponent />,
  document.getElementById('one')
);

ReactDOM.render(
  <MyComponent />,
  document.getElementById('two')
);
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use a `class` to define elements to render in:

```
<div id="my-id-one" class="render-here"></div>
some html
<div id="my-id-two" class="render-here"></div>
```

Then in `js`:

```
let elements = document.getElementsByClassName('render-here');
elements.map(element => ReactDOM.render(
  <MyComponent />,
  element
));
```